# Is it possible to select nth element of a Bootstrap col class to create unequal columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap v4.6, I am wondering if it is possible to access the nth element of a col in order to change the size of it. Basically, I want 2 cards with unequal columns on the top, and 2 cards with unequal columns on the bottom.

```
                    <!doctype html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                  <!-- Required meta tags -->
                  <!-- video for setting up SASS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ovw43Dkp44 --> 
                  <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

                  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
                  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"> 
                  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> 
                  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo&family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
                  <title>Card Mockup</title>
                </head>

                <body>


                    <!-- Cards w/ button below text-->

                      <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex">

                        <div class="card">
                             <a href="#" class="stretched-link"></a>
                            <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
                          <img class="card-img" src="images/santorini.jpg" alt="gov">
                          <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column card-overlay">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Dynamic Contact Patch Characterization</h4>
                            <div class="row mx-0 mt-auto btn-group">
                              <div class="col-10 content">
                                <p class="card-text">
                                  Get unprecedented insight into the contact patch through accurate and high-resolution contact pressure maps measured at high-speed dynamic conditions.
                                </p>


                              </div>
                                <div class="px-0 pr-1">
                               <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block stretched-link">Learn More</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex">

                        <div class="card">
                             <a href="#" class="stretched-link"></a>
                            <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
                          <img class="card-img" src="images/thirdCity.jpg" alt="gov">
                          <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column card-overlay">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Dynamic Contact Patch Characterization</h4>
                            <div class="row mx-0 mt-auto btn-group">
                              <div class="col-10 content">
                                <p class="card-text">
                                  Get unprecedented insight into the contact patch through accurate and high-resolution contact.
                                </p>


                              </div>
                                <div class="px-0 pr-1">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block stretched-link">Learn More</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4  d-flex">

                        <div class="card">
                             <a href="#" class="stretched-link"></a>
                            <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
                          <img class="card-img" src="images/city.jpg" alt="gov">
                          <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column card-overlay">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Dynamic Contact Patch Characterization</h4>
                            <div class="row mx-0 mt-auto btn-group">
                              <div class="col-10 content">
                                <p class="card-text">
                                  Get unprecedented insight into the contact patch through accurate and high-resolution contact.
                                </p>


                              </div>
                                <div class="px-0 pr-1">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block stretched-link">Learn More</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>



                    <!-- end of cards with button on bottom --> 

                  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
                  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
                 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

css code:

```
        $theme-colors: (
    "primary": #0074d9,
    "danger": #ed1c24
    );

    /* card  css/scss */ 


    /* affects the image size of the card  */ 
    .card-img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 375px;
    width: 100%;

    }

    /* overlay on card */ 
    .card-overlay {
    padding: 20px;

    }

    /* header for title in card #2 */ 
    .card-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    } 

    /* used to add shadow on second card */ 
    .gradient-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 42%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
    }

    /* changing font size for second card */ 
    .card-text {
    font-size: 16px;

    }

    /* defining how card looks */ 
    .card {
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;

    border-radius: .27rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 1 1px #d4d4d5;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;

    }

    /* defining outside look for both cards */ 
    .card-block {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, .1);
    box-shadow: none;
    }





    @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";


    /* line to the left of the text in card #2 */ 
    .content {
    border-left: 2px solid #ed1c24;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    /* Adjust the value to move the bar down */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* Add margin to create space at the bottom */ 

    } 




    /* changing components of header h3 & p for smaller screen sizes */ 






    @media (max-width: 1199.98px) { 

    .card-text {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .card-img {

      object-fit: cover;
      height: 320px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    }


    @media (max-width: 991.98px) {

    .card-img {

    object-fit: cover;
    height: 310px;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .card-text {
    font-size: 15px;

    }



    }

    @media (max-width: 767.98px) {


    .card-img {

    object-fit: cover;
    height: 370px;
    }

    .card-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    }

    }


    @media (max-width: 575.98px) {

    .card-text { 
    font-size: 16px;
    }

    }
```

Here is an image of what I would want the cards to look like if I had 4 of them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvvmj.png

As seen in this image, I would want the first card to be a larger size (about 67% of the page) and the second card to be about 33% of the page. Under that, I would want the third card to be a size of 33% and the fourth card to be about 67% of the possible card. My end goal is I would want it so that when I add a new section for the card, it goes into the first card section, and  then what was in the first section goes into the second.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using Bootstrap breakpoints? You could have 2 rows with 2 cols in each.

So it would be like this

col-9 and col-4 (total of 12)
and for the bottom col-4 and col-9.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/